# Error while installing sql developer 4 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, linux, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I am getting below java version conflict error while installing sql developer in my ubuntu 14.04. Although i am using JDK8 as prescribed on oracle download page for this version still not able to find the issue. Below is the error . I simply downloaded the zip file from oracle page. Please help !

```
found java version to be 

 Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 1997, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights 
reserved.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/ide/osgi/boot/OracleIdeLauncher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understang try below  steps :-

1. Using Root try below steps
2. Install sqldeveloper first
3. Check the installation path of jdk installed in your system.

   `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64`
4. Use any editor and add the above path to

   `/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf`
5. SetJavaHome